# Use of Conditional Tense

Tags: gramática, condicional

The use of the conditional tense in the below sentence seems strange to me and I can't find out why it's being used:

> Hoy Miguel se despertó temprano y comío su desayuno con sus padres y
>   sus hermanos. Mientras sus hermanos tambien se **irían** a estudiar y
>   sus padres **irían** a trabajar, hoy Miguel **iría** a su primer día
>   de clases.

Why is the conditional tense used here? It's strange from an English standpoint, but is this a common way of saying things in Spanish?

Comment: Where is the sentence from? I’d expect the pretérito perfecto with ‘hoy’.

Comment: The text comes a kindle book of short stories I found on Amazon. It’s a book for learning Spanish.

Comment: It is a way of writing that it's not common in the spoken language. Think of it as if you say: While he **would go** to his first day of school, his brothers **would go** to study and his parents **would go** to work as well. The thing is that there's have to be agreement between "iría" and "irían". You could also use "future" and replace iría=irá and irían=irán

Comment: That makes a lot of sense, DGaleano. I think it was just kind of an odd tense given the context of the paragraph.

Comment: It sounds terrible, even if it's not wrong. The first two conditionals should be indicative imperfect (*iban*). I understand the rationale for the conditional as future-of-the-past but I doubt any native speaker would utter such a thing.

Comment: @pablodf76 I think if a preterite action came in between it would sound better BUT I went back now and Googled the story.  The tenses in the original story are all over the place.  I thought between two *irse* and one *ir* something seemed weird, but suspicions confirmed:

Comment: https://books.google.com/books?id=AnCbDwAAQBAJ&lpg=PT13&ots=PgDtLDkGSt&dq=Hoy%20Miguel%20se%20despert%C3%B3%20temprano%20y%20com%C3%ADo%20su%20desayuno%20con%20sus%20padres%20y%20sus%20hermanos.%20Mientras%20sus%20hermanos%20tambien%20se%20ir%C3%ADan%20a%20estudiar%20y%20sus%20padres%20ir%C3%ADan%20a%20trabajar%2C%20hoy%20Miguel%20ir%C3%ADa%20a%20su%20primer%20d%C3%ADa%20de%20clases&pg=PT14#v=onepage&q&f=false

Comment: I've seen the conditional used this way in English, in the first chapter of a style of biography that I dislike -- and try to stay away from. My personal name for it is the *portentous introduction*. // This particular sentence is supposedly setting up a contrast between Miguel's plans for today vs. his brothers' plans, but it doesn't work, because the brothers are going to be doing the exact same thing he is.  This writing feels like chalk going the wrong direction on a chalkboard.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The conditional is the future of the past.  It means that, relative to the current *past* time frame, the action will occur at some point in the future.

The important thing is that it does not shift the time frame forward to that time.  Thus, if your sentences were written with the past tense as one of the commenters suggested, then the next action would come *after* Miguel and his brothers going to school and his parents going to work.

But more likely than not, the next sentence is something like, *Miguel se duchó y se vistió con su nueva camiseta*.  Notice then the order of action:

> Wake up → breakfast → shower → dress → go to school / work

Nonetheless, the narrative order is

> Wake up → breakfast →  <sup>[will]</sup> go to school / work → <sup>[but first]</sup> shower → dress

Another commentor mentions they might use the future.  That would also work: the factor involved is (1) in the *present* time frame, have they already gone? If so, must use conditional. And (2) if in the *present* time frame, are they still eventually going to go?  If so, use future, but if something got cancelled and we know that they will definitely not, use conditional.

Also, whenever conditional is used as a future-of-the-past, you can replace it with *ir a [verb]* and it should make much clearer sense for non-natives:

> Hoy Miguel se despertó temprano y comío su desayuno con sus padres y sus hermanos. Mientras sus hermanos tambien se **iban a ir** a estudiar y sus padres **se iban a ir** a trabajar, hoy Miguel **iba a ir** a su primer día de clases.

The double use of *ir* is probably why the author opted for *iría*.  If you use other base verbs it sounds a bit better.